# Ubuntu 18.04 - firewall

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

Can someone tell me which firewall is better to use for ubuntu 18.04? On previus version I used firestarter. Maybe is alternativ firewall? Firewall must have function for sharing the internet.

Best regards,
Jure

Comment: Software recommendation questions are off-topic. Non-programming questions are off-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Firestarter](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firestarter) is a GUI for managing Ubuntu's firewall so it is not a firewall by itself. Alternatively you could use [GUFW](http://gufw.org/) which is a GUI also to manage `ufw` firewall on Ubuntu